# :BufExplorer and its split variants sends me to another tab

Tags: buffers, plugin-bufexplorer

If I have BufExplorer open in another tab, any of the following commands will send me to that other tab instead of opening BufExplorer in a new subwindow in the current tab:

```
:BufExplorer
:BufExplorerHorizontalSplit
::BufExplorerHorizontalSplit
```

This was not the behaviour in older versions of BufExplorer or Vim.  I do not want to be warped to another tab.  I want to look at the subwindows in my current tab.  Is there any way to get the old behaviour back?

I am using Vim 8.2 and BufExplorer 7.4.23.

Comment: It should would be helpful if downvoters would explain their downvoting.

Comment: I did not realize that my question was off-topic.  It doesn't seem to be off-topic according to the [guidance for this site](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  It also isn't clear whether the behaviour was due to Vim or the plugin.

Comment: I'm not sure this conversation is going anywhere productive. [meta] is the appropriate place to build consensus on on-topicness when the voting and close-voting processes fail. And, a quote from [help/on-topic]: "Questions about Vim plugins are on topic but be aware that bug reports and feature requests for a plugin would be better off in that plugin's issue tracker. Most of the plugins available on Github use the built-in issue tracker. (The 'Issues' tab in the top menu.)"

Comment: The thing is that it's unclear whether this is a bug or even an issue.  There might already be a way to tailor desired behaviour.  The on-topicness is also *not* unclear based on the passage you quoted (I cited that page in my comment).  I will try github, but downvoting a question in the face of the preceding is inappropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted behaviour that I'm trying to avoid is due to BufExplorer's "Locate Buffer" feature, which sends the focus to the tab and subwindow of the selected buffer (if it is opened elsewhere).  According to the `F1` help for BufExplorer, this feature can be toggle off by pressing the `a` key when in BufExplorer.